# Alternative to Symmetrical Difference (Analysis) in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, cartography

I am trying to create a buffer that includes the green buffer where it is not intersected by the purple buffer (Purple buffer is mostly under the green buffer).

I don't have the symmetrical difference tool available to me.

Heres a screenshot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbkcxqw3iux3l8o/Screenshot%202014-12-03%2012.00.56.png?dl=0

Answer (score 5):

Using ArcGIS I would use the [union tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Union/00080000000s000000/). This will give you a layer that combines both the 'purple' and 'green' buffers into a single layer.

[image: Union from ESRI help pages]

From this output you can select just the 'green' areas which don't have cover 'purple' areas. You can either do this by looking in the attribute table and select the areas where the purple FID is -1. Alternatively you could do a [select by location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002q000000) and select all areas from your union output that intersect the purple area and then switch the selection.

Once you have just the areas you are interested in you can right click the layer and export the selected features to create a .shp file which will just contain the 'non-purple' 'green' areas.

Comment: The Erase tool is also worth mentioning in this workflow, both from within [ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000m000000)(Advanced licence) and from [ET Geowizards](http://ian-ko.com/)(free).

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be repeating this process or attempting to model/script it...then using a GP tool such as the [Union](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000) tool as @MAJ742 suggests is certainly the best option and your best answer.

If I understand your question correctly and this is a one time thing or you are just playing around with your data...you can try the [Clip option](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m80000000p000000) on the editing toolbar (not the Clip GP tool) which allows you to discard areas that intersects.

Your workflow would be to:

- layer the Purple feature on top of the Green one
- start editing session
- select purple feature
- Edit menu on toolbar > Clip
- buffer = 0.000
- "Discard the area that intersects"

Union tool is certainly more robust...but this is a potential alternative.  This will edit existing data and not create new data so backup original copies.